# Expectation of piecewise functions coupled by brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

I am stuck on a problem involving two quantities, $R_\alpha(t)$ and $R_\beta(t)$, whose evolution over time depends on the price of an asset $S(t)$. Suppose that $S(t)$ follows a geometric brownian motion:

$$dS(t)=\mu S(t)dt+\sigma S(t)dW_t$$

We have that:
$$\begin{align}
d\log(R_\alpha)&=
\begin{cases} 
      -\frac{\gamma}{\gamma{}S(t) + S(t)} & S(t) > \gamma^{-1}\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)} \\
      0 & \gamma\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)} \leq S(t) \leq \gamma^{-1}\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)} \\
      -\frac{1}{\gamma{}S(t) + S(t)} & S(t) < \gamma\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)}
   \end{cases},\\\\
d\log(R_\beta)&=
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{\gamma{}S(t) + S(t)} & S(t) > \gamma^{-1}\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)} \\
      0 & \gamma\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)} \leq S(t) \leq \gamma^{-1}\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)} \\
      \frac{\gamma}{\gamma{}S(t) + S(t)} & S(t) < \gamma\frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)}
   \end{cases},\\\\
g(t) = \frac{R_\beta(t)}{R_\alpha(t)} \implies d\log(g(t))&=
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{S(t)} & S(t) > \gamma^{-1}g(t) \\
      0 & \gamma{}g(t) \leq S(t) \leq \gamma^{-1}g(t) \\
      \frac{1}{S(t)} & S(t) < \gamma{}g(t)
   \end{cases},
\end{align}$$
with $0<\gamma\leq1$, and $\frac{R_\beta(0)}{R_\alpha(0)}=S(0)=1$. To be clear, $R_\alpha(t)$ and $R_\beta(t)$ are dependent on time only through the price $S(t)$.

For example, consider $\gamma = 0.9$ and simple initial values $R_\alpha(0), R_\beta(0), S(0)=1$. If the price then moved up to $S(\Delta{}t)=1.5$, $R_\alpha$ would decrease (and $R_\beta$ would increase):

$$\begin{align}
\log(\frac{R_\alpha(\Delta{}t)}{R_\alpha(0)})&= \int_1^{1.5}{
\begin{cases} 
      -\frac{\gamma}{\gamma{}S(t) + S(t)} & S(t) > 0.9^{-1} \\
      0 & 0.9 \leq S(t) \leq 0.9^{-1} \\
      -\frac{1}{\gamma{}S(t) + S(t)} & S(t) < 0.9
   \end{cases}}dS(t) \\\\
&\implies \log(\frac{R_\alpha(\Delta{}t)}{R_\alpha(0)}) \approx -0.1422
\end{align}$$

Is it possible to get an expression for $R_\alpha(t)$ and $R_\beta(t)$ in terms of only $S(t)$'s parameters? It seems like there should be an exploitable symmetry but after a few weeks of head-scratching, I am not sure how to take it any further. My end goal is to get their expectations at some terminal time $T$.